# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, and suppose that $f(x)+f'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients, and suppose that
>   $f(x)+f'(x)>0$ for all $x$. Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$.

I studied the case when $f_1(x)=x^2$ and $f_2(x)=x^3$. However, I'm not able to start de problem. Is anyone is able to give me a little hint?

Comment: Hint: Multiply by $e^{x}$

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Hint: Find $x_0$ where $f$ achieves its global minimum and look a little bit to the left of it to show that $\min f$ can't be $\le 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)+f'(x)>0$$
$$\Rightarrow e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)>0$$
$$\Rightarrow \int e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)dx>0$$
$$\Rightarrow e^xf(x)>0$$
$$\Rightarrow f(x)>0$$

Comment: What kind a method is that? I do not understand how you do to move from the third to the fourth line. Can you explain to me? Do you use a theorem or method good to you?

Comment: Have you covered integration by parts yet? Alternative just notice that $\frac{d}{dx}(e^xf(x))=e^xf(x)+e^xf'(x)$ so its integration by recognition.

Comment: @IanMiller I think there's a flaw in your proof since you didn't use the fact that $f$ is a polynomial. For instance, note that if $f$ is given by $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ then $f+f'>0$ but $f(x)<0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: I agree with Brandon.

Comment: @anne_bauval Proof is fine, integrate from $y$ to $t$. This gives the expression $e^tf(t)-e^{y}f(y)>0$. Since $f$ is polynomial, the limit as $y$ goes to $-\infty$ of $e^yf(y)$ is $0$.

Comment: Yes this is (an example of) what must be added to the proof to salvage it. Personally I find it clearer (than ian's answer) to say *directly* that $g(x):=e^xf(x)$ is increasing *and* its limit at $-\infty$ is $0$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0, f(x)+f'(x)=a_nx^n+(na_n+a_{n-1})x^{n-1}+...a_1+a_0>0$. 
$lim_{-\infty}(f+f')(x)=lim_{+\infty}(f+f')(x)=+\infty.$ Thus $f$ has a global minimum $u$, $(f+f')(u)=f(u)>0$ since $u$ global minimum, $f(x)>f(u)>0$ for every $x$.